# Wordpress beginner - custom header javascript and nav menu integration

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Problem

1. I am looking to integrate the following custom header to a Wordpress site, and have faced some challenges in (1) integrating the javascript smoothly into the header/functions php and (2) having the menu from the website autopopulate into the structure of the custom header. Our website uses the IWEB Business theme. Per recommendations I've seen online, I want to have the js and css files within the child theme, then use the functions php to call them.

What I've tried

2. I've had some success making the javascript work by (1) using a plugin which places it into the header and (2) pasting the javascript and css directly into the header php. These are not the smoothest ways of integrating, and I would prefer to have the scripts called and populate from the theme folders.

To do this, I put the following enqueues in the functions php. Like the source code, I then placed respective link for css and script for javascript in the header php head and body. This did not seem to work and call either the javascript or the css.

The second challenge I'm facing is how to integrate our existing menu and navigation with this custom header. Would I need to create a new navigation function in the navigation js? Where in the html source code should this nav element go? Do the nav elements need to be different than those in the Theme code?

Appreciate any help and advice on making this run smoothly!

````
<----theme header code---->
<div class="inavbar">
                <?php if ( function_exists( 'max_mega_menu_is_enabled' ) && max_mega_menu_is_enabled( 'primary' ) ) : ?>
                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                        'theme_location' => 'primary',
                    ) ); ?>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
                            <button class="menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                                'theme_location' => 'primary',
                                'menu_class' => 'nav-menu',
                            ) ); ?>
                    </nav>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
<----custom header code---->
<div class="main">
                <nav id="cbp-hrmenu" class="cbp-hrmenu">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Products</a>
                            <div class="cbp-hrsub">
                                <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner"> 
                                    <div>
                                        <h4>Learning &amp; Games</h4>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Catch the Bullet</a </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                         </li>
                        </ul>
                       </nav>
                      </div>
<----theme nav javascript---->
/**
 * File navigation.js.
 *
 * @package iwebbusiness
 */

( function() {
    var nav = document.getElementById( 'site-navigation' ), button, menu;
    if ( ! nav ) {
        return;
    }

    button = nav.getElementsByTagName( 'button' )[0];
    menu   = nav.getElementsByTagName( 'ul' )[0];
    if ( ! button ) {
        return;
    }

    // Hide button if menu is missing or empty.
    if ( ! menu || ! menu.childNodes.length ) {
        button.style.display = 'none';
        return;
    }

    button.onclick = function() {
        if ( -1 === menu.className.indexOf( 'nav-menu' ) ) {
            menu.className = 'nav-menu';
        }

        if ( -1 !== button.className.indexOf( 'toggled-on' ) ) {
            button.className = button.className.replace( ' toggled-on', '' );
            menu.className = menu.className.replace( ' toggled-on', '' );
        } else {
            button.className += ' toggled-on';
            menu.className += ' toggled-on';
        }
    };
} )(jQuery);
            <----end theme nav javascript---->
           

function hrzdropdown_scripts (){
//css
wp_enqueue_style( 'hzcomp', get_theme_file_uri( '/inc/css/hzdropcomponent.css' ));
wp_enqueue_style( 'hzdef', get_theme_file_uri( '/inc/css/hzdropdefault.css' ));

//JQuery
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('cbpmenu', get_theme_file_uri() . '/js/cbpHorizontalMenu.js', array('jquery'), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('cbpmenumin', get_theme_file_uri() . '/js/cbpHorizontalMenu.min.js', array('jquery'), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('modernizr', get_theme_file_uri() . '/js/modernizr.custom.js', array('jquery'), false, false);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hrzdropdown_scripts' );```


  [1]: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/05/horizontal-drop-down-menu/
  [2]: https://github.com/codrops/Blueprint-HorizontalDropDownMenu
  [3]: https://wordpress.org/themes/iweb-business/
````

Answer (score 0):

Hello it's a little hard to know where the problem lies with only that much info, but here are some ways you can find out:

First Adding the JS and CSS files:
I would recommend you to use get_stylesheet_directory_uri() instead of get_theme_file_uri(), since it will always use your currently active theme, like this:

```
function hrzdropdown_scripts (){
//css
    wp_enqueue_style( 'hzcomp', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .  '/inc/css/hzdropcomponent.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'hzdef', get_stylesheet_directory_uri( ) . '/inc/css/hzdropdefault.css');

//JQuery
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('cbpmenu', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/cbpHorizontalMenu.js', array('jquery'), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('cbpmenumin', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/cbpHorizontalMenu.min.js', array('jquery'), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('modernizr', get_theme_file_uri() . '/js/modernizr.custom.js', array('jquery'), false, false);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hrzdropdown_scripts' );
```

After that open your frontend and check your console if there are any 404-errors (most likely wrong directory, missspelling, wrong active Theme, etc).

This code should work correctly, given that your files exist and are spelled correctly.

The question regarding the menu is also fairly vague, but you might achieve what you want using the [wp_nav_menu()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) function, wich renders your already configured menu.

Hope this might help.

Comment: Thanks Christoph, will give this a run and see how it goes! Apologies for the vagueness, will try to upload more of my code for clarity. First time on Stack Overflow, had some trouble putting the links in as well :D

Comment: No Problems, I hope my answer is still somewhat  usefull to  solve your problem. Its somewhat Hard to provide all the neccessary Information within a complex System like wordpress :D

Comment: Thanks Christoph, I got the javascript running. Now I need to tackle the menu function. I added 3 code elements to the above question, including the main theme header section, the custom header section, and then the javascript navigator. My trouble is not knowing where to place the wp_nav_menu in the custom header, as well as coordinating the different tag names that the custom header uses. Would I need to make a new elementID and change the tags?